# Tensor Tensor("mrcnn_detection_1/Reshape_1:0", shape=(1, 60, 6), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I am using `mask_rcnn` inferencing with  thread it shows this error

`Tensor Tensor("mrcnn_detection_1/Reshape_1:0", shape=(1, 60, 6), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.`

How can solve it, thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a read of [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and about [reproducible examples of the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you are facing. Only once you amend your question it can easily attract attention of people who can help you out.

Comment: write your questions with more details, your code,complete error